# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error while using scanf

Tags: c++

I am trying to input data using scanf function for simulation. However, it is giving the above error at scanf. Some part of code is given below. It was working earlier but now it throwing this error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include "normdist.h"
using namespace std;
double initial_stock_price, expiration_time, volatility, R;
int no_of_discrete_barriers, no_of_trials;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &expiration_time);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lf", &risk_free_rate);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%lf", &volatility);
    sscanf(argv[4], "%lf", &initial_stock_price);
    sscanf(argv[5], "%lf", &strike_price);
    sscanf(argv[6], "%d", &no_of_trials);
    sscanf(argv[7], "%d", &no_of_discrete_barriers);
    sscanf(argv[8], "%lf", &barrier_price);
```

Comment: What command line arguments are you passing?

Comment: Remove all those `#include` directives and the `using namespace std;`, and simply write `#include <stdio.h>`. They serve no purpose in the code you've shown.

Comment: I you should check if argc >= 9 before trying and exit if not

Comment: I am passing values as  1,0.05,0.25,50,20,100000,25,20 respectively un argv[]

Comment: `int argc` -- What is the value of `argc`?  In any event, you should never write a program that doesn't first check the value of `argc` if you're going to access `argv` in any way.  Don't be surprised if `argc` isn't what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the program with arguments separated by a comma? You should be calling the program like this:

```
./program 1 0.05 0.25 50 20 100000 25 20
```

When I call it this way it does not crash on my computer.

Also, as commented above, always check in the beginning of the program if argc is >= 8, if not - display program's usage and exit.

Comment: I am calling this inputs from product->scheme-> arguments in xcode via command line tool

Comment: Can you try to call it via the command line as shown above (outside of vs code)? Maybe there is a typo somewhere in the configuration file and the arguments are not passed properly.